# Algebra question: Find the minimum of $x-y$ among all ordered pairs of real numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the minimum of $x-y$ among all ordered pairs of real numbers $(x, y)$, $x$ and $y$ between 0 and 1, where there exists a real number $a \neq 1$ such that
$$ \log_{x}a + \log_{y}a = 4\log_{xy}a. $$

Comment: Do you know how to convert between different base logarithms?

Comment: Welcome to maths.SE. Please tell us what you have tried yourself so we can help with the real problem and don't waste everybody time telling you things you already know.

Comment: Thank you, i got the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
\log_x a + \log_y a &= 4 \log_{xy} a\\
\frac{\ln a}{\ln x} + \frac{\ln a}{\ln y} &= 4 \frac{\ln a}{\ln xy}\\
\frac{\ln x + \ln y}{\ln x \ln y} &= \frac{4}{\ln x + \ln y}
& \ln xy = \ln x + \ln y\\
(p+q)^2 &= 4pq & p:=\ln x, q:=\ln y\\
(p-q)^2&=0\\
p&=q\\
x&=y
\end{align}